# Windows Driver: Could I call an exe/bat in kernel or user mode driver?

Tags: windows, driver

I am developing a WWAN module and need to release new firmware by Windows Update.
Currently we plan to implement a Windows kernel/user mode. Once the driver is installed on Windows system(Win10/Win11) the driver's inf will put our fw update tool(.exe) to driver installation folder, and the driver will call the tool to execute fw update.
The final goal is submit this driver to Windows Update so than we can release new fw by Windows Update.

So my questions are:

1. Could I call an exe or bat file in our driver?
   If yes, Could any one share an example or sample code?
2. If answer to Q1 is no, is there any other method that will let us distribute fw by Windows Update?

Comment: User mode drivers have access to the API. That said,  you have to impersonate an interactive user for a gui.

Comment: It's certainly reasonable to ship firmware as part of a driver. However, the choice of an EXE is perhaps more surprising. Your driver runs as part of the kernel and has direct hardware access, that EXE does not. Why don't you simply include the firmware as a binary object in your driver?

Comment: The kernel is not a good place to start a usermode process.

Comment: Thank for everyone's advices. But the tool is the only one way for updating FW. And we are considering how to trigger the tool by driver